# Making Selected Range into an Array and doing stuff with it

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to teach myself VBA writing some little things. I'm trying to make something that allows you to select some data and then calculates the mean and variance. My code is as follows :

```
Sub VarianceCalculator()

    Dim k As Integer
    Dim SelectedData As Range
    Dim SelectedDataArray() As Variant
    Dim Var As Double
    Dim Mu As Double

    On Error Resume Next    
        Set SelectedData = Application.InputBox("Select a range of data to be 
        calculated", Default:=Selection.Address, Type:=8)    
    On Error GoTo 0

    SelectedDataArray = Range(SelectedData.Address)    
    k = UBound(SelectedDataArray)    
    Call VarianceCalculatorWithArray(SelectedDataArray, k)    
    MsgBox ("The selected data has variance " & Var & " and  has mean " & Mu)        
End Sub

Sub VarianceCalculatorWithArray(Data() As Variant, k As Integer)

    Dim Var As Double    
    Dim Mu As Double    
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim i As Integer

    ReDim Data(k) As Variant   
    Mu = 0
    Var = 0
    For j = 0 To k
        Mu = Mu + (Data(j)) / (k + 1)    
    Next j

    For i = 0 To k    
        Var = Var + ((Data(i) - Mu) ^ (2)) / (k + 1)    
    Next i    
End Sub
```

I think the error is that somehow the data is not getting transferred into the array but I can't find a solution to this.

Thanks!!

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code and checking what is in your variables?

Comment: What is the error you are getting and on what line.

Comment: BTW, here is a place to start. It will give you a general intro. Not to deep.http://www.excelvbatutor.com/vba_book/vbabook_ed2.pdf

Answer (score 0):

There are two major problems:

(1) If you want to pass the variables `Var` and `Mu` from one procedure to another you'll have to declare them as public variables before the first procedure. The alternative is to setup `VarianceCalculatorWithArray` as a function.

(2) The array `Data()` is 2D as a range consists of rows and columns. So, if you want to use an element from this array, you'll have to address it as `Data(1, 1)`. Also note, that this range array starts with row 1 and column 1. Therefore your `for...next` statements should start with 1 and not with 0.

Note, that you can always set a breakpoint in order to check if data is transferred into the array.

Comment: To avoid guessing if `Data` array is indexed from 0 or from 1, you should always use `LBound()` and `UBound()` functions that check the lower and upper bound of the given array. In your case it would be: `For j = LBound(data, 2) To UBound(data, 2)`